# Use C# bindingredirect to downgrade a referenced dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assembly-binding-redirect

NET experts,

I have a problem and hope you can assist.

Is it possible to to downgrade a dependency reference using the binding redirect feature in app.config / web.config ?

I have two referenced dll's in my application. These are strongly named and one (core.dll) depends on another (common.dll)
I am trying to reference an older version of the common.dll library.

I'm getting this error:

```
Assembly 'Core, Version=3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87dca562359a030a' 
uses 'Common, Version=3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87dca562359a030a' 
which has a higher version than referenced assembly 
'Common, Version=3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87dca562359a030a'
```

I've tried using this binding redirect in the app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Common" publicKeyToken="87dca562359a030a" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="3.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

This does not resolve the error.

We are developing the core & common dependencies.
Can a change in the source projects (core & common) resolve this problem?
I made sure the core.csproj does not require a specific version of common.
In the csproj file of core, I have this:

```
<Reference Include="Common, Version=3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87dca562359a030a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Common.3.1.0\lib\net35\Common.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Is it at all possible to downgrade a dependency using bindingredirect?

I would appreciate any help I can get!

Thanks,

Eyal